# Creating divs within div, to appropriate div via nested for loop.

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

First off I'll apologize for not inserting the code here; Im new and trying to get the feel for this, hence I uploaded my code via the photo. Hopefully that is better for understanding.

So essentially what I want my code to do is is create the appropriate number of div meals for every day of the regiment schedule selected. Given the number of days selected via radio, that is the number of divs to be created. Given the number of meals selected via radio, that is the number of divs to be created within the days div. However, it only loops all the meals for the entirety of the regiment selected into the first div created.

For instance if the regiment selected is 1, it creates 3 days of regiment, and if the meals selected is 4, its suppose to create 4 meals for every day of regiment, but my code gives me all meals of regiment in the first di without looping onto the next div.

I dont know what Im doing wrong. Id really appreciate the help.

[Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhqnI.png)

Comment: You need to add your code...

Comment: People answering the question would really prefer if the code was in text format for copying+pasting. ...and an ulrelated tip: id of an element must be unique, you can't have multiple divs with id 'meal_information', for example.

Comment: @algoni I had a feeling I had to do that.